# UI changes done in Netbeans do not reflect in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

I am mainly using Eclipse for my project. For Swing GUI part, I find using Netbeans is more user-friendly. Hence, only for building UI, I am using Netbeans for the same project.

I developed a form using Netbeans. So, corresponding .java file got generated in Eclipse also. After working on it for few days, I went to Netbeans and changed name of a JPanel. But, the same change is not reflected in corresponding .java file in Eclipse.

Before this, I have done such changes in Netbeans and even have seen the changes getting reflected in Eclipse version of the project. But, I don't know what went wrong this time. I even tried refreshing, cleaning etc.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just one advice: Stop using that devils GUI designer in NetBeans. Use Windowbuilder Pro plugin for Eclipse which provides you various layouts instead of just GroupLayout in NetBeans. Altough it would be best if you stop using any of them...

Comment: @brano88 sorry I cant see differencies

Comment: @mKorbel Generated code is much more clear.

Comment: @Vikram each of them is different GUI Framework, based on AWT and Swing methods

Comment: @brano88 forgot about GroupLayout, this is special LayoutManager, generated bunch of code lines, change that to GridBag..

Comment: @mKorbel ...Or MigLayout. :)

Comment: @mKorbel and brano88...
Thanks for the advice. But, my Q is (considering that it is not possible for me to use Windowsbuilder Pro plugin in Eclipse), if I make a change, as minor as changing name of a JPanel using Netbeans, then the same should be reflected in .java file in Eclipse too or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to delete everything from the workspace and checkout everything again. After that, it is working fine.